# Switch between angular test/dev module and production module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing and an Angular app. In e2e tests, I want to mock some of the request to the server and pass through some i.e I want to use [e2e httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend).

Here is Vijittas example of how to use the HttpBackend.

```
` http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/DQHdk/ `
```

Now, here is the dilemma: When I am testing I want my application to boostrap with development module i.e.

```
<html ng-app="AppDevModule">
```

and when I run the server I want the production module to be included.

```
<html ng-app="AppCoreModule">
```

but I don't find it reasonable to change the HTML whenever I want to change between development mode and production mode.

[The documentation of e2e httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend)

provides a code snippet for including a development module, but they didn't mentioned anything about the problem and the inclusion of the dev app.

I am using angular testacular. I tried to configure it in the e2e tests like this:

```
describe("DHCP Client e2e. ", function () {


    beforeEach(function () {


        var fakeAppModule = angular.module('AppCoreModule', ['AppCoreModule', 'ngMockE2E']);

        fakeAppModule.run(function ($httpBackEnd) {

            var networkInterface = [
                {
                    'secondarySubnets':[
                        {"dhcpOfferOptions":{"dnsServers":["8.8.8.8"], "offerTime":"400", "leaseTime":"600"}, "rangesLimits":[],
                            "network":"192.168.0.0", "slash":"24", "gateway":"192.168.0.1",
                            "isDynamic":"dynamic", "description":"asdsadsa"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'secondarySubnets':[
                        {"dhcpOfferOptions":{"dnsServers":["8.8.8.8"], "offerTime":"400", "leaseTime":"600"}, "rangesLimits":[],
                            "network":"192.168.0.0", "slash":"24", "gateway":"192.168.0.1",
                            "isDynamic":"dynamic", "description":"asdsadsa"}
                    ]
                }
            ];

            $httpBackEnd.whenGET('/^\/view\//').respond(200, '<div></div>');
            $httpBackEnd.whenGET('/r/networkInterface').respond(200, networkInterface);
            $httpBackEnd.whenGET('./../main/webapp/r/networkInterface').respond(200, networkInterface);

        });


        fakeAppModule.config(function ($provide) {
            $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);

        });
    });
```

but, things do not go as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following thread: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/3Xm7ZOmhNp0 
it looks like **mock backend is ment to be used when the real one is not yet implemented**. After this is in place the real one is recommended to be used as maintaining two versions may lead to tests not really proving the production application working correctly.

To sum up switching between two application modules for testing and production should be avoided if possible.